# I cannot import CSV file?

Tags: python, csv, data-science

I am completely new to python and programming in general.

I want to do the Famous "Titanic" Data Science Project but I am unable to read the CSV file although I uploaded them. I use Jupyter and Python 3.

I downloaded all CSV Files several times.

[image: screenshot]

```
# data analysis and wrangling
import pandas                as pd
import numpy                 as np
import random                as rnd

# visualization
import seaborn               as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot     as plt
%matplotlib inline

# machine learning
from sklearn.linear_model  import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.svm           import SVC, LinearSVC
from sklearn.ensemble      import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.neighbors     import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes   import GaussianNB
from sklearn.linear_model  import Perceptron
from sklearn.linear_model  import SGDClassifier
from sklearn.tree          import DecisionTreeClassifier



##Acquire data

train_df   = pd.read_csv('../input/train.csv')    #here I get the error
test_df    = pd.read_csv('../input/test.csv')
combine    = [train_df, test_df]
```

Error: FileNotFoundError

Should I change the Directory Path? But if so in what way ?

Comment: Yes, you should change the path. Please show the relevant part of the directory tree (where's the Python script, and where are the `.csv` files).

Comment: csv files are in folder Titanic so why do you use `../input/` ?

Comment: Just to be safe, either use the full path of the csv, or use `os.path.join` to create your path @DaNickste, check my answer below :)

Comment: C:\Users\myname /Desktop I made a screenshot in my original Post as well

Comment: Relative paths are resolved from the working directory, not the script location.

Comment: Mad Physicist can you elaborate on that further? As I mentioned before I am an absolute beginner ...

Comment: This means that if you are running your script from `/user/folder1/folder2` and provide the path as `../input/train.csv`, the csv will be looked at `/user/folder1/input/train.csv`

Comment: Devesh Kumar Singh ah ok thanks. And where should I unpack it instead?

Comment: Check my answer for more description @DaNickste

Answer (score 2):

Just to be safe, provide the `full` path of the csv file in both files to load your dataframes

```
train_df   = pd.read_csv('<path_to_csv>/train.csv')  
test_df    = pd.read_csv('<path_to_csv>/test.csv')
combine    = [train_df, test_df]
```

Or if you know the directory of the csv file, use `os.path.join` to create the full path

```
import os

folder = "<path_to_csv>"

#Full path of csv files
train_path = os.path.join(folder, 'train.csv')
test_path = os.path.join(folder, 'test.csv')

#Use full path to open csv file
train_df = pd.read_csv(train_path)  
test_df = pd.read_csv(test_path)
combine = [train_df, test_df]
```

Also as an addition, if you know that the csv files are in the same location from where the script is run, you can use `os.path.dirname(__file__)` to get the current folder as well.

Comment: `os.dirname(__file__)` is handy if you know the CSVs are next to the script

Comment: Great tip! I added it to the answer @MadPhysicist Please take a look and consider upvoting if it looks good :) PS it's `os.path.dirname(__file__)` :)

Comment: `getcwd` can change externally: you can run your script from wherever you want. The location of the script presumably won't.

Comment: You are right @MadPhysicist Updated my answer to fix that!